# Kafka-Manager Web UI not loading

Tags: apache-kafka, yahoo-kafka-manager

I have started kafka-manager on centos VM and below are its logs.

```
[info] o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
[info] o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
[info] o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.compiler=
[info] o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.name=Linux
[info] o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.arch=amd64
[info] o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.version=3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64
[info] o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.name=root
[info] o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.home=/root
[info] o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.dir=/root/Confluent_kafka/kafka-manager-1.3.3.21
[info] o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:3181 sessionTimeout=60000 watcher=org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@73687e45
[info] o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:3181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
[info] o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:3181, initiating session
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - zk=localhost:3181
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - baseZkPath=/kafka-manager
[info] o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:3181, sessionid = 0x16565ff95660000, negotiated timeout = 60000
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - Started actor akka://kafka-manager-system/user/kafka-manager
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - Starting delete clusters path cache...
[info] k.m.a.DeleteClusterActor - Started actor akka://kafka-manager-system/user/kafka-manager/delete-cluster
[info] k.m.a.DeleteClusterActor - Starting delete clusters path cache...
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - Starting kafka manager path cache...
[info] k.m.a.DeleteClusterActor - Adding kafka manager path cache listener...
[info] k.m.a.DeleteClusterActor - Scheduling updater for 10 seconds
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - Adding kafka manager path cache listener...
[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Prod)
[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9000
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - Updating internal state...
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - Updating internal state...
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - Updating internal state...
[info] k.m.a.KafkaManagerActor - Shutting down kafka manager
```

Tha kafka manager starts perfectly but the WEB UI does not load at all.
The IPV6 is disabled and the netstat shows this

```
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:9000 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 2670/java
```

Can someone help in this.

Comment: Try to stop the firewall (`systemctl stop firewalld`) which should be running on CentOS by default and try again.